# How to set font size of Grid using Slider in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am created WPF Project. In this i  have used GridControl and Slider! I have used slider Value to change FontSize of GridControl via `Binding` and `INotifyProperty`. Problem is that it changes value of FontSize but it doesn't apply and generated `Null Object Reference Error` at:

**CS FILE:**

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            // ... Get Slider reference.
            var slider = sender as Slider;
            // ... Get Value.
            double value = slider.Value;
            // ... Set Window Title.
            this.grid.FontSize = value;   // Error HERE
        }
```

**XAML CODE**

```
 <Grid>
           <Slider Minimum="15" Maximum="30" Value="{Binding GridFontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" />

           <dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" Name="grid"  Margin="0,25,0,0">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                         <dxg:TableView Name="View" AllowEditing="False" ShowTotalSummary="True" PreviewMouseDown="View_PreviewMouseDown" MouseDown="View_MouseDown"  />
               </dxg:GridControl.View>
            </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
```

How to solve this Problem? Can anyone answer my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give your `Grid` a name using the `Name` property:

```
<Grid Name="YourGrid">
    <Slider Minimum="15" Maximum="30" Value="{Binding GridFontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" />
        <dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" Name="grid"  Margin="0,25,0,0">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="View" AllowEditing="False" ShowTotalSummary="True" 
                PreviewMouseDown="View_PreviewMouseDown" MouseDown="View_MouseDown" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
</Grid>
```

Now you can refer to it in your code by that name:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, 
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // ... Get Slider reference.
    var slider = sender as Slider;
    // ... Get Value.
    double value = slider.Value;
    // ... Set Window Title.
    TextElement.SetFontSize(YourGrid, value);
}
```

Comment: IT GENERATES : `Error 2 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' does not contain a definition for 'FontSize' and no extension method 'FontSize' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Sorry, that is an `Attached Property` and so it needs to be set differently. Please see my corrected example.

Answer (score 0):

There are invalid values, so you need to put your code into a try catch. In the catch set it to zero instead. Also check for values below zero and set to zero.

I have similar code where font size is also bound to a slider and have a converter on the fontsize below:

public class IntToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{

```
public object Convert( object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
{
    double result = 0;

    try
    {
        result = (double)((int)value);


    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    return result;
}

public object ConvertBack( object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
{
    return (int) ((double)value);
}
```

}